# Page redirect from external php file (in ajax call)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, redirect, iis

I have this Salesforce "Web-to-Lead" form that I'm working with (on an IIS server), and I got it validating properly in an Ajax call (using the roscripts.com ajax validation as a starting point... this uses the Mootools library to carry out its Ajax functions), as well as sending all of the validated data using cURL, however I want the form to redirect to a new page after validation succeeds. The Ajax call runs every time the Submit button is clicked and either displays errors on the page or runs whatever is included in the "else" section of the validation code.

The Ajax function:

```js
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
  $('registerForm').addEvent('submit', function(e) {
    new Event(e).stop();
    var log = $('log_res').empty().addClass('ajax-loading');
    this.send({
      update: log,
      onComplete: function() {
        log.removeClass('ajax-loading');
        //adding a header redirect here works, but redirects every time ajax call runs, regardless if validation succeeds or not
      }
    });
  });
});
```

The "action" php file function:

```html
<?php 
if (rule){ //validation errors } 
else { //where all of the logic happens after validation succeeds

//cURL function 

//redirect attempts:
header( 'Location: http://www.place.com'); // doesn 't work

echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2" ; url="http://www.place.com">'; //resets the form, but doesn't redirect to www.place.com 
};
?>
```

I'm totally stumped here, I can't get this darn thing to redirect, no matter how hard I try. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is the return in either case? just add an result to know in the oncomplete if the valdation was successfull, if so, redirect.

Comment: Redirection inside a file called by Ajax just redirects on the server side and returns the output of the second file to your javascript callback. It doesn't redirect the page the user is looking at.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell of MooTools AJAX, the `onComplete` handler will fire any time AJAX is finished -- even when there are errors. That may be fine for removing your loading message, but you'll probably want to use `onSuccess` for a successful handler and `onFailure` for a failed request. While your script doesn't appear to be using MooTools directly, this is how MooTools AJAX works.

See the "Ajax!" section on http://mootools.net/ for an example.